# using step detector android function in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, android-sensors

I want to create an android racing game that allow many players to race each others, the player animation movement depends on the distance traveled by the user in the real life. to develop this game I used android studio and LibGdx.
to detect the user movement I used step detector and its working fine as follows:

```
    // Step Counter

 SensorManager sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);


    sManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                                      float steps = event.values[0];
                                      textViewStepCounter.setText((int) steps + "");
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

                                  }
                              }, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    // Step Detector
    sManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                                      // Time is in nanoseconds, convert to millis
                                      timestamp = event.timestamp / 1000000;
                                  }

                                  @Override
                                  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

                                  }
                              }, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

private void setupDetectorTimestampUpdaterThread() {
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
           // textViewStepDetector.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp));
        }
    };

    detectorTimeStampUpdaterThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    detectorTimeStampUpdaterThread.start();
```

Now my question, how can I use this code in libgdx, is there any function that counting user steps in Libgdx
Thank you